# How to rebase local branch on gerrit change?

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a local commit that is based on a gerrit change (not yet submitted).
I created my local branch by fetching the gerrit change and creating a new branch from that.

Now the gerrit change has a new patchset uploaded, so I'd like to rebase my local change too. How can I do that?

Tried to fetch the change

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/69/111569/10
```

but I couldn't reference it when rebasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "creating a new branch from that", I assume it's also a local branch, right?

Check the commit sha1 value of the local commit. Suppose it's `abc123`.

Reset your local branch to the latest patchset first. Is it `refs/changes/69/111569/10`? If so,

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/69/111569/10 && git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard
```

Note that `git reset --hard` wipes your uncommitted changes. Stash them if any.

Cherry-pick the local commit to the updated local branch.

```
git cherry-pick abc123
```